# Move category title above category page image

Tags: magento2, category-view

I want to move the category title to this image:

[image]

Is it possible to do it with the layout.xml or is CSS needed to move it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added css to the image and the title:

```
@media all and (min-width: 768px), print {
   .category-view{
   width: 79.16666667%;
   float: right;
   -ms-flex-order: 2;
   -webkit-order: 2;
   order: 2;
 }
  .page-title-wrapper{
    width: 79.16666667%;
    float: right;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
  .page-title-wrapper.product{
    width: 100%;

  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){

  .category-view{
    width: 75%;
  }

  .page-title-wrapper{
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

Now it gives the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code in your theme's `catalog_category_view.xml` file right before the closing body tag `<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="-"/>`.

You may also be able to place it in the admin category page layout xml updates area, though offhand I'm unsure if M2 allows the `<move>` tag in that location.

Comment: The solution you offered doesnt work, it overlays the image over the filters.

Comment: Can you add a copy of your `catalog_category_view.xml` and a screenshot of the overlap? What version of Magento2 are you using? You could also try `<move element="page.main.title" destination="columns.top" before="category.view.container"/>`. I tried this on m2 instance I have spun up and it moved the title above the image. Though, I also have the filter located in a different area than your original screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have fixed it with CSS, see my sollution